# Where Clause for ionic SQLite Plugin

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, cross-platform, cordova-plugins

I'm using [Sqlite](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite/) plugin in my ionic 3 app.
I have saved and fetched data successfully but when I use Where Clause for fetching data against specific ID using following Query:

```
const query = "SELECT * FROM " + `${table}`  + " WHERE project_id=" + `${project_id}`;
       this.database.executeSql(query, []).then((result) => {
            console.log('RESULT: '+ JSON.stringify(result));
        }, err => {
          console.error('Error: '+ err);
        });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your query as follows and you will get the response.

```
const query = "SELECT * FROM " + `${table}`  + " WHERE project_id=?";
       this.database.executeSql(query, [project_id]).then((result) => {
            console.log('RESULT: '+ JSON.stringify(result));
        }, err => {
          console.error('Error: '+ err);
        });
```